# I integrated a template into my angular project and I encountered a problem in these two files : core.min.js and script.js

Tags: javascript, angular, templates

**index.html**

```
<html class="wide wow-animation" lang="en">
<body>

  <app-root></app-root>

  <!-- Javascript-->
   <script src="assets/js/core.min.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

[The error displayed at the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bk5Rf.png)

[The hierarchy of my files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppMiF.png)

--> The template is displayed but neither navbar nor carousel works .

Comment: You are using javascript/jquery code which is outside of angular life-cycle. Use Angular pre built module for carousel or other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

External javascript files should be added to the `angular.json` file under "scripts":

```
"scripts": [
  "assets/js/core.min.js",
  "assets/js/script.js"
]
```

Official docs: https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#style-script-config

From the docs:

> An array entry for the styles and scripts options can be a simple path string, or an object that points to an extra entry-point file. The associated builder will load that file and its dependencies as a separate bundle during the build. With a configuration object, you have the option of naming the bundle for the entry point, using a bundleName field.
>
> The bundle is injected by default, but you can set inject to false to exclude the bundle from injection. For example, the following object values create and name a bundle that contains styles and scripts, and excludes it from injection:

Finally, you are using jQuery, which I would avoid in Angular if at all possible. You're proabably going to encounter some issues along the way.